# Oracle Query to get the records which are not in the results sets

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where I need to query the table to see the how many records are not present from the particular record set.

for eg -I have a record set  (deptno1 ,deptno2 ....deptno100)

Table - Emp1

I would like to know how many records from that record set are not present in the table emp1.

If I run this query - select * from emp1 where deptno notin(deptno1....deptno100) it gives the records other than 100 records eventhough those 100 records might be in that table

Comment: Can you add the example in a fiddle? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18

Comment: So in this example you want to return depno2 if it doesn't exist in emp1? And you don't have that list of departments in a table? It sounds like you might be looking for something in the format `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'deptno1' deptno FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 'deptno2' from dual) a WHERE depno NOT IN (SELECT deptno FROM emp1)`

Comment: Yes .I have 100 values in the data set(dept no 1 to dept no100) and I would like to know what are the records are missing in Emp1 table that are there in the data set ,provided that I  don't have the access to that dept table

Comment: What is a "data set"? What do you mean by "I have a record set"? These terms don't describe anything that exists in the database. Do you have them **in a table**? Are they the result of some other query? How do you "**have**" them?

Comment: Apologize for the confusion here. When i say "record or data set" that meant the 100+ records(deptno 1 to deptno 100) which doesn't exist in database or in table

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
WITH data (deptno) AS (
  SELECT 'deptno1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'deptno2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  -- ...
  SELECT 'deptno100' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT d.deptno
FROM   data d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN emp1 e
       ON (d.deptno = e.deptno)
WHERE  e.deptno IS NULL;
```

Or, with slightly different syntax that should work on early Oracle versions, either:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'deptno1' AS deptno FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'deptno2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  -- ...
  SELECT 'deptno100' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT d.deptno
FROM   data d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN emp1 e
       ON (d.deptno = e.deptno)
WHERE  e.deptno IS NULL;
```

or

```sql
SELECT d.deptno
FROM   (
         SELECT 'deptno1' AS deptno FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'deptno2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         -- ...
         SELECT 'deptno100' FROM DUAL
       ) d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN emp1 e
       ON (d.deptno = e.deptno)
WHERE  e.deptno IS NULL;
```

*[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f1e37f432a55ecbd0348474a80e7d8dc)*

Comment: It's throwing syntax error "Expected keyword AS but got "(" at line 3, column 11)" from the first line

Comment: @saru It works fine for me on Oracle 11 and Oracle 18; see the db<>fiddle link I've added to the answer. If you are running Oracle 10 or earlier then (please, please upgrade) you can try either of the other two versions of the answer I've added.

Comment: In the With clause ,do we need to give 100 records separately in each select query?

Comment: @saru You say in the question "I have a record set (deptno1 ,deptno2 ....deptno100)" if you have that as a result set from another query then use that. If you are inputting the values then you need to generate 100 rows and you can do that using `UNION ALL` or from another table or, if you have one, from a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the values using connect by.

with d(dept) AS
( select 'deptno' || to_char(level)
from dual connect by level <= 100
)
select d.dept
from   d
left join emp1 e
on (d.dept = e.deptno)
where  e.deptno is null;